# mongodb taking up ridiculous amounts of storage for no reason

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to use something on https://repl.it to store data, but with more storage amount, so i chose Mongodb.

Thing is though, if i set something simple like `{ smackos:1 }`, the storage amount is already 8 kilobytes

My code is on: https://replit.com/@codingMASTER398/mongotest#index.js

Why is this happening? I want my Smackos to take up as less storage amounts as possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can view storage status with this query

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').stats({})
```

Note that the total size is sum of collection size plus the size of every index in collection and all collections always has an index for _id field.